# C# DLLImport causing too many IO operations

Tags: c#, performance, dllimport

I have a C# program which calls a C++ dll using DLLImport(stdcall).

But using the Process Monitor I found that everytime I call a function in the C++ dll it causes three IO operations to open the DLL file, read it and close it.

[image: IO operations]
The function in C++ dll i'm calling is static. I don't have the source of the C++ dll to change it. What can i do to avoid these excessive IO operations? Can i use DLLImport to load a dll from memory instead of file? Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the behavior when calling a normal 'managed' dll? There is a difference or this is the standard way?

Comment: Is this behavior caused by the CLR or by the DLL itself? Try calling an empty function in the DLL and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Calling a normal managed dll will cause these IO operations too, but only in the first call. The next calls on the dll will use the same "pointer" to the dll opened in the first call, so the dll will not be opened again.

Comment: I'd have to guess that c:\program files (x86) is not located on the network.  What *is* on your network?  Start with the usual suspects, anti-malware etc.

Comment: I really don't think that the CLR itself tries to load the DLL each time you call functions in it. Even if the Process Monitor displays series of `CreateFile` operations originated from `EventProcessor.exe`, it doesn't necessarily mean that this is because *you* call `DllImport()`ed method: it could be that the method *internally* invokes `CreateFile` or `QueryNetwork` for its own purposes.

Comment: Try calling the same method from unmanaged code, and see if there are similar IO operations occurring.

Comment: If the DLL was loaded every time a function call was made that would negate much of the benefit of using a DLL in the first place.  DLL's are loaded into your process space and subsequent calls go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load DLL explicitly and then make your call. Keep the pointer to the DLL and unload it before closing your application.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);


IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary("library.dll");

FreeLibrary(pDll);
```

Comment: This answer is based on the belief that the diagnosis in the question is correct. It is not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed there is something wrong in the scenario in question. It should not happen that DLL gets unloaded after each call (if that's what's really going on). Loading it explicitly increases DLL reference counter making it less likely for DLL to be unloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The analysis presented in your question is simply incorrect. If it was correct, then `DllImport` would be useless.

No, when you call a function imported with p/invoke, the DLL that is loaded stays loaded. The p/invoke system does not load and unload DLLs on each and every call to the imported functions.